# What can I do to start gaining weight?

Tags: diet, weight-gain, bmi

I am 6 ft tall 20year old boy. I currently weigh 60Kgs.

I take regular diet which consists of morning breakfast, milk, day lunch, evening snacks, dinner and half liter milk in night as well.
In spite of all this, I am not able to get fat and gain weight.

What is the problem? What should be my diet plan and what should I eat/what not.
Is there any problem with metabolism ? As I feel hungry even after 1-2 hours of heavy lunch/dinner.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what you eat exactly and how much physical activity you undertake. Also note [that there have already been several questions on this topic](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=gain+weight), so please explain how these didn't solve your problem.

Comment: Are you wanting to gain weight for building mass?  If so check out: http://stronglifts.com/gomad-milk-squats-gallon-gain-weight/  .  Do spend time to clarify your question so that any recommendations actually match your goals.

Comment: No, i dont want to gain weight to build mass. I want to be normal as per my height-weight chart. and i do look thin thats why.

Comment: Do you have any idea what your resting metabolic rate is (RMR), which would be your BMR multiplied by an activity factor (1.5 for sedentary office work to 2.0 for heavy construction work)?  Do you have any idea how many calories you spend while working out?  It's quite possible you simply aren't eating enough.

Comment: Simple, eat more. If you think you already do eat enough to gain weight, you're just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a fast metabolism but it would be very useful if you shared an example of your daily intake so we can see how much and what you eat.

You should eat a lot of proteins and the right ammount of carbs and have enough sleep (at least 8 hours a day) in order to gain quality weight.

When I started to train I went to the gym 4 times a week, each time exercising 2 muscle groups and abs and used the following diet:

**Morning:**

3 egg whites

1 cup of cereals with low-fat milk

**Snack:**

sanwich with integral bread and turkey ham

low-fat yogurt

**Lunch:**

pasta or rice

300g of meat (turkey, chicken, horse or fish)

vegetables

**Snack:**

2 apples

**Dinner:**

300g of meat

vegetables

If you are a healthy person, eat the right ammount of quality food, exercise well and sleep enough sooner or later you will get the right results. Many people complain about not being able to gain weight but in most cases it is not because of metabolism or health issues but the matter of incorrect daily habits.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Horse meat? I didn't know they sold that.

Comment: I'm from Europe otherwise haven't seen it in any store in USA while being there.

Comment: There's really no point in cutting out all of the fat. If you're trying to gain weight then fat is not a bad thing. It's actually much easier to gain muscle mass if you have a decent store of fat (not like a beer gut though). Instead of egg whites only, eat the whole egg, change the milk to whole milk, and yogurt to regular yogurt (but real yogurt not yoplait as that's mostly made of sugar).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not gaining weight in spite of eating high calorie, high protein foods at regular intervals of 2-3 hour:

- Before thinking of weight gain by diet way, check other medical problems.
- Blood examination to check-hyperthyroidism or any other disease condition.
- Stool examination for any worms problem etc.
- For this consult a Doctor (general physician), confirm you don’t have any medical problem. If you have any medical problem then start the treatment with proper therapeutic diet. Your weight gain problem will get solved.
- If you don’t have any medical problems then go to a dietitian for weight gain because weight gain is not that easy to do on your own.

Comment: make sure you use an empty line before beginning a list, else it won't render correctly :-) And would you care to explain how high protein foods are more effective than for instance more carbs or fat?

Comment: Yup, please do explain. Protein rich food is often recommended for weight loss, as it's supposed to make you feel less hungry. It's also less kcal/g than e.g. fat.

Comment: @ Ivo Flipse Weight gain program is actually a treatment. Many of times in underweight or malnutrition there is the deficit of energy with deficiency of proteins. With deficiency of proteins hormones formation gets disturbed because hormones are made of proteins. Main part of muscle, blood (Hemoglobin) and bone is protein. So without increasing protein % of food you can’t improve these things.

Answer (score 0):

Eat more than you burn, e.g. Michael Phelps eats mad amounts of food but he isn't overweight because he burns mad amounts of calories.

Calculate your daily calorie intake and estimate how much you burn through manual work, walking, exercise and sports, etc.

If comparison of the two does not result in substantial excess of calories you will not be gaining weight. 
However, if the math does add up then I'd agree with @Madhuri Sathe's suggestion about medical examination.